# Unable to use sqlcmd command shows libodbc.so.2

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

Whenever I tried to use the sqlcmd command in my terminal im getting and error like 
"sqlcmd: error while loading shared libraries: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you didn't install the [unixodbc-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unixodbc-dev&searchon=names) package which depends on the [libodbc1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libodbc1&searchon=names) package and contains the missing shared library.

You can install it with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install unixodbc-dev
```

Related:

- [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#ubuntu17)